# Is there an equivalent in Dart of the instance_variable_set method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dart, instance-variables, dart-mirrors

If not, is there anything like this on the horizon?

This is the one feature of JavaScript, Ruby, and Perl that I can't live without. I know you can fake it with a hash member, but I want to be able to create (arbitrary) "first class" members from a parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's nothing that can set a field that doesn't yet exist. The [mirror API](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_mirrors/InstanceMirror.html) can be used to set fields that already exist, and may eventually be extended to support defining new fields dynamically.

Comment: Cool. The mirror API should let me do what I want, I think. I.e. I can construct a default instance based on the class and an identifier, then populate it's members using reflection. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JimBelton please note that mirrors is only really a VM thing for now, until we get to it for dart2js. Are you building client or server apps?

Comment: Seth: I'm interested in dart for it's ability to be used both server and client side. What I'm interested in mirrors for is parsing and persistence. Client side isn't essential, but without it, parsing has to be done server side, so it would be nice to see client side in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "noSuchMethod" method on a class to intercept setter / getter, and store the received value in a map.

For example (I can't remember the syntax exactly...):

```
class Foo {
  var _dynamicProperties = new Map<String,Object>();

  noSuchMethod(String function_name, List args) {
    if (args.length == 0 && function_name.startsWith("get:")) {
      // Synthetic getter
      var property = function_name.replaceFirst("get:", "");
      if (_dynamicProperties.containsKey(property)) {
        return _dynamicProperties[property];
      }
    }
    else if (args.length == 1 && function_name.startsWith("set:")) {
      // Synthetic setter
      var property = function_name.replaceFirst("set:", "");
      // If the property doesn't exist, it will only be added
      _dynamicProperties[property] = args[0];
      return _dynamicProperties[property];
    }

    super.noSuchMethod(function_name, args)
  }
}
```

And then you can use this in your code as follows:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = "Hello, World!";
print(foo.bar);
```

Of course, this can lead to typos that will not be checked by the type checker, e.g.:

```
foo.bar = "Hello";
foo.baz = "Hello, World!"; // Typo, meant to update foo.bar.
```

There are ways you have type-checker validation by using redirecting factory constructors and an implied interface, but then it starts to get complicated.

Side note: This is what [JsonObject](https://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject/blob/master/lib/JsonObject.dart) uses to convert a JSON map to a class type syntax.